# Understanding Javascript Function in base 16

Tags: javascript, hex

I have this neat little function in JavaScript that is very useful and clean:

```
CreateGuid: function () {
        var guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
                v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });

        return guid;
    },
```

I would like to modify it slightly to be able to randomly generate an alpha numeric sequence.

The only part of this function that I don't under stand is:

```
r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)
```

Apart from the fact that it is a ternary operator what does this do?

Comment: [Binary bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Binary_bitwise_operators).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be clearer if you look at the binary writing of 0x3 and 0x8 :

```
 0x3.toString(2) => 11
 0x8.toString(2) => 1000
```

What we're doing here is bitwise operations :

- first a `and` with `11` at the bit level (truncating to only the two last bits, that is doing `%4`),
- then a `or` with `1000` (setting one bit, adding `8`).

The whole would probably be less confusing directly written as

```
var guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
.replace(/x/g, function(){
   return  (Math.random()*16|0).toString(16)
})
.replace(/y/, function(){
   return  (Math.random()*4+8|0).toString(16)
})
```

Comment: It seems to me that `Math.random()*16|0 === 16`should be true occasionally, assuming the single pipe strictly truncates decimal places. However, I ran this 100m x 10 times and it was never true. Same for `Math.random()*4+8|0 === 12`. Is this expected? Am I crazy?

P.S. Thank you for providing the "less confusing" option. That will help future developers from hating me and I always appreciate that!

Comment: @beez `Math.random()` is in `[0-1[`. It can't be 1. So `Math.random()*16` is in `[0-15[`. It can't be 16.

Comment: Derp! RTFM. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random): `The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.`
Thanks, @dystroy!

Answer (score 3):

looks like it's equivalent to `r % 4 + 8`

http://jsfiddle.net/8TFMg/1/ :

```
0 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 8
1 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 9
2 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 10
3 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 11
4 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 8
5 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 9
6 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 10
7 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 11
8 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 8
9 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 9
10 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 10
11 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 11
12 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 8
13 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 9
14 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 10
15 & 0x3 | 0x8 = 11
```

Comment: Yeah it seems just to be looping through 8,9,10,11 and inserts them at point y in the string :P